# Connect to Raspberry Pi through SSH without Port Forwarding

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, raspberry-pi3

I have a raspberry pi laptop with a raspberry pi 3 running Jasmine, and was wondering if I could connect to it through SSH no matter what WiFi network the Raspberry pi was connected to.

Example: I leave my Pi Laptop at McDonald's, connected to their free WiFi, I then go home, and on my chromebook I SSH into my Pi Laptop.

And I need to do this without port forwarding since I don't have access to McDonalds WiFi settings or most other network's settings, so I can't port forward my Pi Laptop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was in your same shoes 4 years ago. I finally decided to use a VPN solution. The best and most reliable for me was Hamachi (now owned by logmein). It might still be free.

https://secure.logmein.com/labs/#HamachiforLinux

I haven't added any new system in a while but here were the commands I typed.

sudo wget https://secure.logmein.com/labs/logmein-hamachi_2.1.0.86-1_armel.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --fix-missing lsb lsb-core
sudo dpkg --force-architecture --force-depends -i logmein-hamachi_2.1.0.86-1_armel.deb

sudo hamachi login
sudo hamachi join xxx-xxx-xxx yourkey

sudo hamachi go-online xxx-xxx-xxx

Also install and add hamachi on your computer.

Now if as long as your Pi and your computer have internet access you will be able to reach it.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this post is old, but thought I might have some useful info.

To connect to multiple pis on different networks without port forwarding I use the service: https://www.remot3.it/web/index.html

You can make a free account on their website. Then, in the terminal of the pis, you can run the commands:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install connectd`

`sudo connectd`

Then follow the steps in the installer and you can view and control all your devices (as long as they have a route to the internet, or even cellular). You can also follow this video once you have an account/the installer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rfr5Ox17S6U

Full disclosure: I'm actually an intern at remote.it this summer, but I thought it might be useful for you.